# How to Send alarm time to other activity

Tags: android, facebook

hi i am new to android i want to create an alarm which rang when the alarm time is found but unfortunately i couldn't make it up please help me out this problem here is my MainActivity.class and SoundActivity.class file any one can tell me how to set  this out please? Thank you package com.toprecur.myalarm;

```
    package com.toprecur.myalarm;

    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;`enter code here`
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewDebug.FlagToString;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.TimePicker;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        protected static final TimePicker timePicker1 = null;
        protected static final Calendar calendar = null;
        protected String FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            OnClickListener setClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                private TextView tvDisplayTime;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext()
                            .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    TimePicker tpTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_time);

                    int hour = tpTime.getCurrentHour();
                    int minute = tpTime.getCurrentMinute();

                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(hour,
                            minute, 0);

                    long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            SoundActivity.class);

                    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            getBaseContext(), 0, intent,
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time,operation);

         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is setsuccessfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            OnClickListener quitClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            };

            Button btnSetAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_set_alarm);
            btnSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(setClickListener);

            Button btnQuitAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_quit_alarm);
            btnQuitAlarm.setOnClickListener(quitClickListener);
        }

        protected Object pad(int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }


and my SoundActivity is as follows below here i want to play music when the alarm sound would rang i have tried lot of methods to get the alarm setted time but i didn't got from my MainActivity.class file to SoundActivity.class file any body can help me out please. thank you.

package com.toprecur.myalarm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SoundActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mPlay;
    public Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);


        MediaPlayer mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarm_rooster);
        mPlay.start();
        Uri soundURI = Uri
                .parse("android.resource://course.examples.Notification.StatusBarWithCustomView/"
                        + R.raw.alarm_rooster);
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).setSound(soundURI);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sound, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should user the putExtra Method to send the data and in the other activity user getExtra method to receive the data.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, float[])

Comment: i had used those methods but i didn't got that

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer for my question using putExtra and getIntExtra finally i got the output for that. anyway thanks to farooq arshad.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
                    //.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour)
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);

                startActivity(intent);
```